# Secure login with hello.js

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, hello.js

I am new to Oauth2 and hello.js and don't understand, how to use it securely.

I was trying singup/login with Google and for me the problem is, that 3rd party Oauth service (e.g. Google) does not return user-details (email, id) to my server. The critical data (id, email) is fetched on the client and then it can be sent to my server by client / browser.
But I cannot make reliable server API which receives arbitrary network-type(google|facebook), userId, password and makes login / signup according to this. Everyone could then register as someone other's = arbitrary social id.

What workflow would You sugest to create an account for Google-authenticated user, in my server?

Edit: sorry, this whole queestion is probably my misunderstanding of Hellol.js purpose. 
In my case, I need something like authom or passport.

Answer (score 0):

> Google adds to the url all the information about user, and there is no secret token

It should only be adding an 'access_token' this is unique session token to make subsequent calls to googles api's on behalf of the user.

Comment: Thanks for answer Andrew. The entire question is my misunderstanding of Hello.js mission/problem-focus, sorry. You did great job with Hello.js.